# How can I use the SHA's on installing Ruby ? What's the risk if I don't verify them?

Tags: ruby, installation, sha

I'm installing Ruby (in order to eventually be able to use Redmine) on my Win 10 laptop.

I realize how critical the whole install process is and I'm wondering if there are real threats not to check the various SHA given there : https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/04/13/ruby-2-2-2-released/.

I guess it's needed if you don't trust the source you're downloading from, but I found it through my usual search engine (ie qwant).

If this verification is really a must-do, how can I do it ?

One of the SHA's given is :

```
SHA1:   7d26835cb7711dfe75f2c10fe38cb85f5ed56df5
```

I'm on Win 10, so I picked one from the .zip list.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent [tampering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamper-evident_technology#Tampering) (but if the download is through http**s** you are safe).

Theory is pretty well introduced [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43332/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-the-downloaded-files).

Hands on side, in short, you need to execute $>sha1sum my_file.exe in PowerShell, and check if the hash is the expected one.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BwzV.jpg